# How to compare two lists to keep matching substrings?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

As best I can describe it, I have two lists of strings and I want to return all results from list A that contain any of the strings in list B. Here are details:

```
A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001', 'dataFile2002']
B = ['2000', '2001']
```

How do I return

```
C = ['dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001']?
```

I've been looking into list comprehensions, doing something like below

```
C=[x for x in A if B in A]
```

but I can't seem to make it work. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were close, use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
C=[x for x in A if any(b in x for b in B)]
```

More detailed:

```
A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001', 'dataFile2002']
B = ['2000', '2001']

C = [x for x in A if any(b in x for b in B)]

print(C)
```

**Output**

```
['dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001']
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked like a charm. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if any element of your list `B` is in x:

```
A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001', 'dataFile2002']

B = ['2000', '2001'] 

c = [x for x in A if any(k in x for k in B)]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
['dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001']
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I would construct a `set` of the years for the O(1) lookup time.<sup>1</sup>

```
>>> A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001', 'dataFile2002']
>>> B = ['2000', '2001']
>>> 
>>> years = set(B)
```

Now, keep only the elements of `A` that end with an element of `years`.

```
>>> [file for file in A if file[-4:] in years]
>>> ['dataFile2000', 'dataFile2001']
```

<sup>1</sup> If you have very small lists (two elements certainly qualify) keep the lists. Sets have O(1) lookup but the hashing still introduces overhead.